# validate inline css in html

Tags: html, css, validation

I have a html file with only inline css attached to tags for styling- like this:

```
<div style="max-width:620px;background-color:#002e6e">
```

How do I validate this inline css to be of version 2.1 or 3.

I found this validator online - https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options

But it can process only css files.

Is there a validator which can parse inline css and validate it.

Comment: Did you try with any HTML validator?

Comment: One detail: you forgot ; after background-color:#002e6e;

Comment: @Firefly The last declaration never needs a `;`. It's recommended, but not necessary.

Comment: The site has a note. Note: If you want to validate your CSS style sheet embedded in an (X)HTML document, you should first check that the (X)HTML you use is valid. link: validator.w3.org